# Loop to split list in different sublists

Tags: python, sorting, loops

I want to split one list of number comparing the first number of the sequence with the next one to figure out if it's bigger, in this case we create that sublist till find one number who is smaller. And each other

```
Inputdata = [45,42,78,120,47,2,50,32,34]
```

compare 45 with 42 is bigger not, so create list just with 45, and start with 42 to compare with the next one till find the smaller than 42:

```
Output = [45] [42,78,120,47] [2,50,32,34]
```

this is my code:

```
data = [45,42,78,120,47,2,50,32,34]

m = (len(data))
i=0
list1=[]
emptylist = True
while i <= m:

 for j in range(i+1,len(data)-1):


    if data[i] < data[j]:
        list1.append(data[j])
        emptylist = False

    else:

        if emptylist:

            list1.insert(0,data[i])
            print list1
            i += j
            list1 = []
            emptylist = True
            break

        else:
            list1.insert(0,data[i])
            print list1
            print j
            i += j
            print i
            list1 = []
            emptylist = True
            i += j
            break
```

My Output is:

```
[45]
[42, 78, 120, 47]
```

and I can't find the problem... any suggestions? thanks

PD1. The idea is create sublist where the first element is the smaller one.

Comment: Are you sure that output is correct?
Output = [45] [42,78,120,47] [2,50,32,34]
seems to have no pattern -- why does the second list have a 47, and why is the third list not split into two after the 50?

Comment: Shouldn't it be i=j instead of i+=j?

Comment: If you see, each first element of list is the smaller one of the sublist

Comment: @anana when i change that, the loop never end

Comment: You should also increment `i` by 1 in case `data[i] < data[j]`. But I'm probably missing something

Comment: I don´t think so, because if data[i] < data[j], still i want compare the same data[i] with the next data[j]

Comment: You're right, but if it never gets to the `else` block, `i` should still be incremented before/after leaving the `for` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
L = [45, 42, 78, 120, 47, 2, 50, 32, 34]

cond = L[0]
res = [[cond]]
for item in L[1:]:
    if item > cond:
        res[-1].append(item)
    else:
        cond = item
        res.append([cond])
```

Now `res`is :

```
[[45], [42, 78, 120, 47], [2, 50, 32, 34]]
```

### Details:

Indexing with `0` gives you the first element:

```
>>> cond = L[0]
>> cond
45
```

We create new list `res` that will hold our result and put the `45`, i.e. the very first element into a list that in turn becomes the first element of `res`:

```
>>> res = [[cond]]
>>> res
[[45]]
```

Now, we iterate over the list starting form the second element. `L[1:]` gives this sublist:

```
>>> L[1:]
[42, 78, 120, 47, 2, 50, 32, 34]
```

Note, `res[-1]` always gives us the currently last element of a list. This itself must be list and we append the next number (`item`) if it is bigger than our `cond`. Otherwise, we append a new sublist with only one element `res.append([cond])`. During the next round we do the same. Therefore, the list that makes up the last element in our `res` will grow as long as `item > cond`. If not, we append a new list with `cond`. Rinse and repeat until the end of the original list.

### Variation

The `L[1:]` makes a copy of `L`. This not the most efficient way of doing it. If we turn `L` into an iterator we can avoid this:

```
L = iter([45,42,78,120,47,2,50,32,34])
cond = next(L)
res = [[cond]]
for item in L:
    if item > cond:
        res[-1].append(item)
    else:
        cond = item
        res.append([cond])
```

Each `next(L)` will give us the next item in the iterator. The for-loop will go over the rest. So in our case it starts at the second element because we called `next()` once.

Comment: Nice! but i´m new in python so i can´t understand something in ur code.. res = [[cond]] and why ur loop is with L[1:] ? even res[-1]

Comment: @taonico Initially `res = [[cond]]` is `res = [[45]]`, since `45` is already used up we want to look at the values after `45`; hence, `L[1:]`. `res[-1]` gives you the last sublist of list `res`, so we keep appending to the last sublist, until we hit a smaller value than `cond`, in that case we make a new sublist. I thought this was a good solution to a good question +1 to both.

Comment: You can use an iterator here, then there's no need of creating an intermediate list using `[1:]`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for the hint. I added a version with an iterator. The effect will only be measurable if the list is reasonably big. Since the OP tries to learn the very basics, slicing seems a bit simpler to get started with than iterators.

Comment: @MikeMüller Really thanks so much, as you can see i´m learning python, your description was really good! thanks, finally i decided use the variation i think is more clear for me.